# Выражение "по самой своей природе"

Tags: орфоэпия, смысл

Верно я понимаю, что ***самой*** здесь от слова *самый/самая,* а не от *сам/сама,* и что поэтому ударение на первый слог: *"по с**а**мой своей природе"?* И всё же мне кажется, что смысл передаётся близкий к слову *"сам",* то есть выражение часто можно заменить синонимичным *"сама по себе".* Правильно я понимаю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: **по самОй своей природе.**

1) Здесь использована падежная форма слова ***сам***.

Слово ***сам*** может быть **местоименным существительным или местоименным прилагательным**, причем формы слова одни и те же. Для ж. рода: САМА, **самОй**, вин. самоё и саму;

Сравнить:

(1) **Природа сама  справится** (местоименное **существительное**, указание на действующий предмет). Другие примеры; сама справлюсь, мне самОй нужно.

(2) **По самОй природе** (местоименное **прилагательное**, **указание на именно этот предмет**).

Другие примеры: Нарушен сам закон (= именно закон). Она само совершенство. Сам начальник звонил. Неверной была сама идея. ***Сама суть армии отрицает человечность.***

[http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=сам](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC)

2) Слово ***сАмый*** — местоименное прилагательное (в указанном словосочетании это  слово не применяется, его значение рассмотрено для сравнения).

Местоимение ***самый*** может употребляться совместно с указательными местоимениями, также оно выражает **предельное** значение, например: **Молодец, физик!!! Видит самую суть!**

***САмая суть*** – это суть, выраженная **предельно** ясно.

Другие примеры:

***В эту сАмую минуту*** (перед указательным местоимением, усилительное значение),

***над сАмой головой, на сАмом верху*** (предельное значение),

***сАмый большой*** (образование превосходной степени прилагательных).

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon! Мне и казалось, что от слова "сам", но ударение почему-то хотелось поставить на первый слог, поэтому и предположил, что всё-таки от "самая".

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, здесь происхождение от "сама природа чего-либо" (ударение на втором слоге), в отличие от "самой сути" ("самая суть"). Смысловой акцент в первом случае делается на первопричине *происхождения* (она единственна), во втором - на главном *содержании* (которое субъективно) чего-либо.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Понравилось сравнение с "самой сутью". :)